# Custom Queries: Joining On Meta Values From Two Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, query, post-meta, meta-query, join-tables

Hi – I'm hoping this is the right place to be asking this question.

I am in the process of moving my full football club website onto Wordpress, therefore using a single database for the information I hold. I'm doing this (for context) to make things easier in the long-run.

Before, there was a database table for Opponents, Matches, Players etc. Now I have Custom Post Types for these. Each entry in these tables has a unique ID that could be referenced in other tables where appropriate: Opponent ID, Match ID, Player ID and so on.

In a Match page, for example, I'd extract and output data from the Opponent and Player tables with joins - a basic example of which would be:

```
$query = "SELECT me.date, me.opponent, me.score, ce.name, ce.ID, me.ID, ce.badge FROM  
matchengine me RIGHT JOIN clubengine ce ON me.opponent=ce.ID WHERE me.ID = ".$id."";
```

From this, I get

```
me.date      ce.name (from ID)    me.score
==========================================
01/01/1900   Team Name United     2-1
```

instead of

```
me.date      ce.id                me.score
==========================================
01/01/1900   200                  2-1
```

What I haven't yet been able to do is to replicate this in Wordpress. I can output info from a single post type i.e. Match, but not yet found the way to extract the relevant data from another post type too (if there *is* one). My instinct is joining two post types on a shared meta_value – or meta_key?

EDIT (11 August): What I've done is taken @SallyCJ's advice and made the Opponent field a Post Object (finally finding out how to import data from CSV as this!). Using the following code within the query calling the 'Match' posts, I am able to output the team name and not just three digit ID code. I'm sure it's rough and ready in Wordpress circles, but it does the job for me.

```
$opposition = get_field('club');
if($opposition) echo $opposition->post_title;
```

Comment: So I suppose you have CPT `match` and `club`? And assuming `$wpdb->posts` is `wp_posts`; for `match` posts, `me.date` = `wp_posts.post_date`, `me.opponent` = the meta (i.e. custom field) named `competition`, `me.score` = the meta named `score`, and `me.ID` = `wp_posts.ID`; and for `club` posts, `ce.name` = `wp_posts.title`, `ce.ID` = `wp_posts.ID`, and `ce.badge` = the meta named `badge`?

Comment: That is, I think, more or less correct @SallyCJ – except for the final two; `ce.ID` corresponds to the post slug (is that `wp_posts.name`?) and `ce.badge` will be the featured image. I have no qualms adding an ID field to the `club` CPT if it makes things easier. Not sure why I didn't in the first place, to be honest...

Comment: It's `wp_posts.post_name` and not `wp_posts.name`. :) So if the meta `competition` for `match` posts have its *value* set to the corresponding `club` post's *ID, slug, or title*, then we can relate the `match` and `club` posts via the `competition` meta/field. Otherwise, you'd need to add a meta (to `match` posts) which would relate the two CPTs - maybe best if the meta value = the `club` post ID.

Comment: Sorry @SallyCJ, I had made a mistake in the code - it's the meta `opposition` that corresponds to the `club` post's _slug_ e.g. `opposition` 248 corresponds to _/club/248_ if that makes sense. So, my aim (or hope?) is to be able to make that relation in the query.

Comment: You actually made another typo in the question.. `WHERE p.post_type = 'match'"` - remove the `"`. :) Anyway, I've posted an answer and hopefully it helps you! Just let me know if you need further assistance. =)

Comment: I've updated the answer.. I missed the "*make that relation in the query*" part of your previous comment.. so hopefully the SQL statement in the updated answer can help you build the query you wanted/prefer to have. :)

Answer (score 1):

So based on our discussion, the meta named `opposition` (for `match` posts) has its value set to the *slug* of the corresponding `club` post; e.g. `club-1`, `club-two`, etc., right?

If so, then you first get the ID of the `club` post using a custom query (see in the code below) and then you can access any data you want from the `club` post such as the post title and content. Just make sure to always check if the post ID (identified by `$club_id` in the code below) is greater than `0` (zero), because otherwise the data you get would be for the current post *in the `foreach` loop*, which is for the current `match` post and not the `club` post associated with that `match` post. (I hope you can understand this..)

```
if ( $latestresult )
{
    foreach ( $latestresult as $post )
    {
        setup_postdata( $post );

        // Get the ID of the `club` post associated with the current `match` post.
        $club_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT ID
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_name = %s
            AND post_type = 'club'
        ", get_field( 'opposition', $post->ID ) ) );

        // Don't use `get_the_title()` with a zero value; so check if $club_id > 0
        $player_name = $club_id > 0 ? get_the_title( $club_id ) : 'N/A';
    ?>
    ...
    <div class="result-info">       
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    ...
    <span class="result-column"><?php echo $player_name; ?></span>
    ... 
    <span class="thumbnail">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $club_id, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
    </span>
    </a>
    </div>
    <?php
    }   
}
```

However, if possible, you should probably better change the ACF field type to [Post Object](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/post-object/), where the *meta value* would be the ID of the `club` post and not its slug. But for that, make sure to set the "Allow Null" to "Yes", and "Select multiple values" to "No" — see [this image](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/post-object-options.png).

And if you can do that, then the code would be **simpler**:

```
if ( $latestresult )
{
    foreach ( $latestresult as $post )
    {
        setup_postdata( $post );

        // Get the ID of the `club` post associated with the current `match` post.
        // Set the third argument to `false` to get the post ID instead of object.
        $club_id = get_field( 'opposition', $post->ID, false );

        // Don't use `get_the_title()` with a zero value; so check if $club_id > 0
        $player_name = $club_id > 0 ? get_the_title( $club_id ) : 'N/A';
    ?>
    ...
    <div class="result-info">       
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    ...
    <span class="result-column"><?php echo $player_name; ?></span>
    ... 
    <span class="thumbnail">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $club_id, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
    </span>
    </a>
    </div>
    <?php
    }   
}
```

### Additional Note

Although this code works:

```
$latestresult = $wpdb->get_results( 
"SELECT * FROM $wpdb->wp_posts
WHERE p.post_type = 'match'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
LIMIT 2"
);
```

I did it using [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/):

```
$latestresult = get_posts( [
    'post_type'      => 'match',
    'orderby'        => 'date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 2, // LIMIT
] );
```

Because that's how we're supposed to do it in WordPress. =) (The other way would be using `new WP_Query( [ ... ] )`.)

Comment: I'd have used Post Object, but found it easier (lazier?) to import multiple entries into text fields @SallyCJ. Using the non-SQL solution is currently returning N/A for all results; perhaps this is because I didn't clarify properly? The post slug is a single number only i.e _/club/100/_ rather than _club-100_. But I'm unable to figure out if it's the `$club_id` query.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really notice the "*single number only*" part.. so if the actual post slug are all numbers, try change the `get_field( 'opposition', $post->ID )` to `str_replace( [ '/club/', '/' ], '', get_field( 'opposition', $post->ID ) )` in the first code of the Original Answer part of my answer.

Comment: if ( $latestresult )
`$club_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "
            SELECT ID
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_name = %s
            AND post_type = 'club'", get_field( 'opposition', $post->ID ) ) );

        $player_name = $club_id > 0 ? get_the_title( $club_id ): 'N/A';`

Have I understood the correction? Sadly, the output is still N/A and yet it feels so close to the solution...

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for updating the answer @SallyCJ - I have replicated it exactly, but the output is still "N/A". Would it perhaps be easier if I were to create a new meta field for the `club` CPT labelled club_id that could then relate to the `opposition` field in the `match` CPT?

Comment: LOL sorry again.. was quite sleepy when I wrote those two comments (that I've removed..) but **yes, it would be**. You could also, if not too bothersome, add `club_id` as a meta for the `match` posts, where that `club_id` would correspond to the `club` post's ID. But whichever option you think is best for your situation, just go with that and let me know once done.

Comment: Please check the updated answer..

Comment: OK, each `club` CPT now has a `club_id` field, a unique number between 1-305. This same unique number is also used in order to customise the slug i.e. _test.URL.com/club/XXX_. In the `match` CPT post, a number is entered into the `opposition` field to correspond with said `club` – I could change this to `club_id` to make things easier? I'm still, sadly, getting N/A – sorry! I feel as if I've explained all this poorly :/

Comment: Or maybe I failed to understand them properly from the start.. xD. So I wanted to confirm, the format of the `opposition` meta is still `/club/{numbers}/`, or is it just numbers now?

Comment: Entered into the `opposition` meta field of the `match` CPT is a number between 1-350, and this is the same number that appears in the slug of the relevant `club` CPT - so opposition 200 corresponds to club 200 that can be viewed at `URL.com/club/200 – does that confirm? Or confuse haha?

Comment: Nope it doesn't, haha! OK, so could you please do [these](https://pastebin.com/VgRP76Ye)? (that will expire in 7 days from now)

Comment: The two screenshots are now available [here](https://www.boroguide.co.uk/images/screenshots/screenshot-1.png) and [here](https://www.boroguide.co.uk/images/screenshots/screenshot-2.png). Not sure they help to be honest. Have tried converting these fields to `Post Objects` as suggested, but can't seem to work out how to import data from CSV file as `Post Objects`. Is it possible?

Comment: Wow, how could that be empty? I mean, if the post *types* `match` and `club` do exist, and that there are `match` posts with the `opposition` field, and `club` posts with the `club_id` field, then there should be a minimum of one row returned from each of the SQL commands.. Are you sure the post type *names* I've used are actually correct?

Comment: Btw, sorry for the late reply.. do you actually still need help with the question?

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if I did something wrong, to be honest. I've now taken one of your earlier suggestions and converted the `opposition` field to a `Post Object` – this is now doing what you said it would, thank you. You've been a massive help on this (and massively patient too!)

Comment: So I guess I should roll back to the [first/original version](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/revisions/310002/1) of the answer? Because I honestly thought it would work for you. :) Can I roll back to that version of my answer?

Comment: I mean, you're saying that everything is OK now, right? xD

Comment: Do, absolutely @SallyCJ. Really do appreciate your time and patience with this, but you were right from the very off - post object is the way to go as it's much more convenient. Or so it seems. I'm sure the way I've structured the code is inefficient, but everything is good :)

Comment: I've just rolled back the answer to the first version, and I hope you'd upvote it once you have the priviledge.  And I think you should write an answer for your question and accept that answer. :)

Comment: Or maybe you don't need to. xD Btw, I upvoted the question for *citing me*. Haha!

Comment: I'm happy to upvote your rolled back answer - after all, you were right at the outset and it **is** much easier to convert the necessary meta fields to Post Object :)

Comment: Thanks @PeteHayman. I'm actually happier to hear that than have the upvote. xD